# edit JSON Objects in JSON Objecs with PHP

Tags: php, html, json

How can i increment x or y in this JSON file? I posted my PHP code to increment the counter, but i dont know how to acces the "infos" -> "x" or "y".

JSON file

```
{
  "counter": 4,
  "infos": {
    "x": 1,
    "y": 2
  }
}
```

PHP file

```
<?php
$contents = file_get_contents('../test.json');
$contentsDecoded = json_decode($contents, true);

$contentsDecoded['counter']++;

$json = json_encode($contentsDecoded);
file_put_contents('../test.json', $json);
?>
```

Comment: `$contentsDecoded['infos']['x']++`?

Comment: sometimes its sooo easy.... it works THANK YOU <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
$decoded['infos']['x']++;
```